# css - style element for broken text (white-space: normal)

Tags: css

In my site I limited the form components to be in a fixed size. at the same time, I allowed the label to break the text when the text is long and I wonder if there is a way to catch whether the label actually broke the text (so i could adjust the fixed height accordingly) or not

note that the label itself comes from the server (as a resource) and the site is presented on many device resolutions so I can't predict whether the text will break or not

my code looks like this:

**HTML**

```html
    <form>
     <div class="long-label">
       <label for="question1">What is your name?</label>
       <input id="question1" name="question1" >
       <span class="error" data-for="question1"></span>
     </div>

     <div class="long-label">
       <label for="question2">What is your favourite colour?</label>
       <input id="question2" name="question2" >
       <span class="error" data-for="question2"></span>
     </div>
    </form>
```

**CSS**

```css
    .long-label {height:60px;}
    .long-label label { white-space:normal;}
```

EDIT:
I've made a codepen example for what I'm trying to achieve
https://codepen.io/smallscalearmageddon/pen/eYNQGJK

I'll try to explain the scenario more clearly:
I have a form in my site with several inputs, labels above them and underneath them there are error spans that are being injected if and when the input value is not valid.

When that happens for a certain input, the error span is pushing the inputs underneath it down and the graphic guy said that it is ugly and the margin between the inputs should be fixed.

so I've fixed the height ({height:60px;}).

unfortunately, the labels above the inputs come from the server as resources in many languages and some of them are making the labels text vey long until it breaks into 2 lines.

when that happens + a validation error is being displayed - the error span is being overlaying the label of the input underneath it.

so what I was asking is:

is there a way to detect when the text breaks into a new line so I could fixed its height accordingly

I hope I was clear now

Comment: No there is not

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: _“(so i could adjust the fixed height accordingly)”_ - adjust it to what, exactly? What is the actual _result_ you want to achieve here? Please give a proper explanation of that first of all.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the input - I've edited the quetion

Comment: Well you could read the actual height of the label element using JavaScript, and then modify the height of the container div accordingly. _“unfortunately, the labels above the inputs come from the server as resources in many languages”_ - what about the error messages, maybe those might go over multiple lines, too, in some languages?

Comment: @Cbroe you are right, the errors also can be long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.long-label {min-height:60px;}
```

### EDIT:

This pen is based on your example: https://codepen.io/ziad-darwich/pen/vYOQpyQ

Comment: Thanks @ZiadDarwich but unfortunately min-height won't make the height of my form-component's fixed. There is an error <span> that is hidden and when it's filled/shown, the component height will expend with it

Comment: maybe posting photos of what you need to get would be great in order to help you more, meanwhile please make sure you close your div tags correction </div> not <div>

Comment: point taken @ZiadDarwich, unfortunately, I can't post a screenshot because it is a process and you need a video to see the issue. is there something unclear in the question I've wrote?

Comment: @armageddon change the height of your form-component from height:nnnpx to min-height:nnnpx ... please try to create a working example on codepen.io or generate pictures of what's happening with you

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I need to give a magrin-bottom to the input above and reside the error span inside that margin. can you please add that to your answer? what you actualy did

Comment: Glad I could help.. keep grinding